# GuestAdditions version mismatch

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile

when I use this command:

```
vagrant up
```

I obtain this error:

```
[machine1] GuestAdditions versions on your host (4.3.36) and guest (5.0.10) do not match.
```

how can I update guest addition from ubuntu shell?

Comment: Guest Addiction to what substance? :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the [vagrant vbguest plugin](https://github.com/dotless-de/vagrant-vbguest)

Install the plugin:

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest
```

Let `vagrant up` it will install the virtual box client if needed.
If you want to force the installation you can run `vagrant vbguest --do install`

Answer (score 2):

You need to upgrade your *VBoxGuestAdditions* ISO either by:

- installing/upgrading the package by running:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions-iso
  ```
- or by downloading ISO file from [this Downloads page](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/).

  Example for macOS:

  ```
  sudo wget -O /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.0.10/VBoxGuestAdditions_5.0.10.iso
  ```

  where version of VBoxGuestAdditions (`5.0.10`) should match installed VirtualBox binaries.

  See: [How to upgrade to VirtualBox Guest Additions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20308794/55075)

---

Consider also upgrading your VM box by:

```
vagrant box update
```

---

For Linux Ubuntu, also check this page: [Setting up VirtualBox Guest Additions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/GuestAdditions).