# GuestAdditions versions on your host (5.1.16) and guest (4.3.36) do not match

Tags: vagrant-windows

I am trying to add more than 1 VM instance through Vagrant 1.9.2 and Oracle Virtualbox. Getting "mounting" problem followed by the error - GuestAdditions versions on your host (5.1.16) and guest (4.3.36) do not match.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38010519/guestadditions-version-mismatch

Comment: This is resolved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GuestAdditions version mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38010519/guestadditions-version-mismatch)

Comment: How did you solve it?